# how to hide/remove all text in-between two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

lets say i have this lump of HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<span class="title">Heading 1</span>
This is a description..<br />
This is the second line..
<div class="image"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

What i want to do using jQuery/JavaScript is hide/remove all text and elements between `<span class="title">` and `<div class="image">`.

I've looked all over and found pretty much nothing. Any ideas on how i could do this?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if the text to be removed was enclosed in HTML tags...

Comment: @Widor i have a rather large database that i would have to edit in order to add tags. i agree though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ZW8q2/1

```
var foo = $('.container').children(':not(br)');
$('.container').html('').html(foo);
```

Comment: This is great. precisely what is needed, however, it doesnt hide the line breaks, any ideas on what would be the way round that?

Comment: Updated my answer - http://jsfiddle.net/ZW8q2/1/ - You can add tags that you want to filter by comma separating them in the :not selector

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
var str = $('.container .title').text() + $('.container .image').html();
$('.container').html(str);
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hCWSY/).

Comment: This won't work if there would be other elements **after** `.container .image` or **before** `.container .title`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Place a  tag around what you want to hide, give div an ID name. So in the end your  will look like:

```
<div id = "hideMe" style ="display:block">...Your Content...</div>
```

Use this javascript:

```
    function hide()
    {
    document.getElementById('hideMe').style.display = "none";
    return;
    }
```

Have the Javascript function called whenever you want to hide the stuff between the div from a button (or other control) like this:

```
<input type= "submit" onclick ="hide()">
```